# linux system stat() method is not working correctly

Tags: linux, string, system, stat, strcat

When I wrote path like this, I stat() was working.

```
char homePath[] = "../../usr/http/";

if(stat("usr/bin",&file_info) == -1)
{
    strcat(sendMessage, path);
    strcat(sendMessage, "\n\nHTTP/1.1 400 Not Found\n");
    return 0;
}
```

but the below code is not working. stat() always returns -1.
I thought strcat is the problem. But when I check the merged path string, It seems ok. Please let me know how to fix it.

```
    strcat(path, homePath);
    strcat(path, target);


    if(stat(path,&file_info) == -1)
    {
        strcat(sendMessage, path);
        strcat(sendMessage, "\n\nHTTP/1.1 400 Not Found\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Have you initialized `path`? Also what is the content of `sendMessage` at the end?

Comment: sure. I'v done it. char path[200] = "";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first character's of path might be unprintable.  Use **strcpy**.  Safer yet, use **strncpy** and **strncat**.

```
strncpy(path, homePath, sizeof(path));
strncat(path, target, sizeof(path) - strnlen(path, sizeof(path)));
```

Read the Linux man pages to see why the **strn** versions are preferred.

Comment: Try running with a debugger and ensuring the strings are correct.  Also, when stat returns an error (-1), use strerror_r() to get the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

How do set homePath and target?

the formating looks fine: http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat

Comment: It is very normal form. homepath = "../../usr/http/"      target="test"

Comment: and when you print path before calling stat? It look ok?

Comment: sure, I tried it. It seemed OK. I wonder that it include invisible data.

Comment: Ok you may want to print a character at a time to make sure there isn't any funny business going on.

However before you do that check ernno to verify the error, 
 #include <errno.h>

and then call :
printf("The stat error is: %s\n", strerror(errno));

because stat should set errno to a specific error value.